# Wordpress crob job performance

Tags: plugins, wp-cron, cron

I am trying to create a plugin which will check data(s) from other mysql table(maybe in the same database with wordpress or not, even in another host), if new data is checked, publish them as a post use the `wp_insert_post` or something else.

Not I want to make the check job as a wordpress crob job which will run every 20 minutes. I am not sure if this is the right way? Would it cause some performance to the wordpress itself?

Also, does the crob job will be triggered even there are no visitor?

BTW, there will be  100K records at most in the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, The action will trigger **when someone visits your WordPress site**, if the **scheduled time has passed**.

So if there no visitors crob job will not be triggered. In your case, it is better if you can run server cron job. 
Performance issue depend on the function you need to run as a cron job.